# Javascript - How do I find out which condition(s) triggered?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following statement:

```
if (height > 4.25 || length > 6 || weight > 1) {
  //Do Something
}
```

Is there a way to tell which of the conditions was met in order for that statement to be true?

Something more elegant than below, which is obviously redundant:

```
if (height > 4.25 || length > 6 || weight > 1) {
  if (height > 4.25){...};
  if (length > 6){...};
  if (weight > 1){...};
}
```

Comment: Put this in a function, check them one by one, return from the first `if` that's `true`.

Comment: on anyways, ultimately you might be ending up writing 3 If statements since all three parameters are different (height, length and weight)

Comment: This would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com since you have working code and are asking for opinions on how to rewrite it.

Comment: There's no indication of what needs to happen in the outer `if` but outside the inner `if`s. Why is that? Wouldn't this be an important part of the solution? Is there a reason you don't just put the results of all three in variables and then use them as needed? Why is this general approach not "elegant" enough? How do we know if we've provided a "more elegant" solution? There's not nearly enough detail here.

Comment: @Dryden how is a simple **Not possible!** answer answers your question when it's possible, have you checked other questions? Have you seen the code in my question?

Comment: @chsdk While your answer is correct, it would still require me to check each individual value to see whether it was undefined or not. What I was looking for was a solution that provided me with the conditions that were met, which apparently isn't possible.

Comment: @DrydenLong yes you will check each result but in the end you will know which condition passed and which one wasn't reached, so it does meet your needs.

Comment: @chsdk: That's the problem with these *"make my code better/more elegant"* questions. They're far too broad and entirely subjective, and that's why they're off-topic and shouldn't be answered. There are functional solutions that would likely help and be very concise, except that this question still lacks detail.

Comment: @squint Fair enough. So I think it's better to delete my answer in that case.

Comment: @chsdk: Up to you. If he sees no benefit in storing the result of a condition over manually re-typing it, then I don't know what else could be done to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not possible!**

You will have to check each option in a separate condition:

```
if (height > 4.25 || length > 6 || weight > 1) {

 if(height > 4.25){
  return true;
 }

 if(length > 6){
  return true;
 }

 if (weight > 1){
  return true;
 };

}
```

And even then you won't know if when height was bigger than 4.25 length wasn't bigger than 6, to know these you will have to go over all the possible combinations:

```
 if (height > 4.25 || length > 6 || weight > 1) {

     if(height > 4.25 && length > 6 &&  weight > 1){
      return true;
     }

     if(height > 4.25 && length > 6){
      return true;
     }

       //and so on...

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think i would do something like this:

```
let height = 2;
let length = 2;
let weight = 2;

var conditions = [
{name: "con1",con: (height > 4.25)},
{name: "con2",con: (length > 6)},
{name: "con3",con: (weight > 1)}
]

conditions.forEach(function(value, key){
if(value.con)
{
console.log(value.name+" was triggered")
}
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can abuse the switch construct:

```
var height = 4;
var length = 7;
var weight= 1;
switch(true) {
case (height > 4.25):
  alert(1);
  break;
 case (length > 6):
   alert(2);
  break;
case (weight > 1):
  alert(3);
  break;
default:
  alert(4);
}
```

Comment: Works only if exactly one of the conditions is true.

Comment: How is this an improvement? Why wouldn't you just use an `if/else if`?

Comment: Well stupid question in, stupid answer out.

Comment: That's great, until people start upvoting it, as they did, which means we must down vote it so that newbs aren't confused as to why this is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can always assign the conditional check to a variable.
something like this:

```
function dimension(height, length, weight) {
    var param = {};
    if ((param.height = height > 4.25) || (param.length = length > 6) || (param.weight = weight > 1)) {
        console.log(param);
        //if (param.height) dosomething_with_height(height);
        //if (param.length) dosomething_with_length(length);
        //if (param.weight) dosomething_with_weight(weight);
    }
}
```

but you know, since its if-or conditional, when some of condition are meet, then the next condition aren't checked.

so if height condition are meet, then length and weight are undefined.
or if length condition are meet, then the height are false, but the weight are undefined.

[image: here some test]

Comment: It's the same answer as mine !!

Comment: @chsdk sorry, i didn't check every answer. just post what i know

Comment: Yes it's always a great idea to come after 15 mins check which answer is working, downvote it, try to optimise it and then post a similar one. Well played.

Comment: @chsdk nope, i dont care with vote on my post, as long as op/whoever can read mine. i just share my knowledge, i dont expect anything in return (including upvote)

Comment: Great, you convinced me.